# python/django adding directory files to db

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I have a folder which contains several pdfs which i would like to add to my db, however with the code below, every time I refresh my page, same data gets added to db again, is there a way to avoid this and only have new data added to the db? Thank you

```
 def index(request):
        path = "/Users/Sam/Desktop/docs"
        mylist1 = os.listdir(path)
        mylist2 = glob.glob(path + "//*.pdf")
        mylist1.pop(0)
        file = []
        for z in mylist1:
            file.append(os.path.splitext(z)[0])
        for (x, y) in zip(file, mylist2):
            p = File(file_name=x, file_path=y)
            p.save()
        all_files = File.objects.all().order_by('file_name')
        return render(request, 'form/index.html', {'all_files': all_files})
```

Comment: in your models you can use unique = True

Comment: It did not work, now I get IntegrityError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try [get or create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create):

```
for (x, y) in zip(file, mylist2):
    File.objects.get_or_create(file_name=x, file_path=y)
```

instead of

```
for (x, y) in zip(file, mylist2):
    p = File(file_name=x, file_path=y)
    p.save()
```

Comment: glad to help you, don't forgot to accept the answer

Comment: I am new to this, how do I accept. Now I'm having another issue, if I remove a file from my folder, is there a way I can have it deleted automatically from dB?